# CMake Test show printf output

Tags: c++, cmake, ctest

I have a Boost test case that goes as follows:

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE my_test

#include <cstdio>
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(my_test_case)
{
    printf("123");
}
```

I tried to build this test case using `cmake`,

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(my_test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -Wall")

enable_testing()

file(GLOB TEST_SRCS main.cpp)

foreach(TEST_SRC ${TEST_SRCS})
    get_filename_component(TEST_NAME ${TEST_SRC} NAME_WE)

    add_executable(${TEST_NAME} ${TEST_SRC})

    # Boost
    ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DBOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK)
    find_package(Boost COMPONENTS unit_test_framework REQUIRED)
    target_link_libraries(${TEST_NAME} PUBLIC ${Boost_LIBRARIES})

    add_test(NAME ${TEST_NAME} COMMAND ${TEST_NAME})
endforeach(TEST_SRC)
```

When I simply use the command `make test`, the output goes as follows:

```
Running tests...
Test project xxx
    Start 1: main
1/1 Test #1: main .............................   Passed    0.00 sec

100% tests passed, 0 tests failed out of 1

Total Test time (real) =   0.00 sec
```

Nothing is shown (using `CTEST_OUTPUT_ON_FAILURE` does not help because I want to see the output even if all tests have passed). I also tried `ctest -V` but it is must more verbose that what I expect

```
UpdateCTestConfiguration  from :xxx
UpdateCTestConfiguration  from :xxx
Test project xxx
Constructing a list of tests
Done constructing a list of tests
Updating test list for fixtures
Added 0 tests to meet fixture requirements
Checking test dependency graph...
Checking test dependency graph end
test 1
    Start 1: main

1: Test command: xxx
1: Test timeout computed to be: 10000000
1: Running 1 test case...
1: 123
1: *** No errors detected
1/1 Test #1: main .............................   Passed    0.00 sec

100% tests passed, 0 tests failed out of 1

Total Test time (real) =   0.00 sec
```

What I really want is **something more verbose than `make test`, but  cleaner compared with `ctest -V`**, like the output below (which I obtained by directly running the binary `./main`):

```
Running 1 test case...
123
*** No errors detected
```

Comment: would [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49923562/how-to-force-cmake-to-write-test-output-after-make-test) have answered your question?